# Break the execution of the loop while reading string, if there is a New line/Space/for particular Letter in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops, break

```
for letter in '''Break the execution of the loop while reading string 
if there is a New line/Space/particular Letter''': 
   print (letter)
   if letter=='space/New Line/particular letter'
   break
```

Here in this if condition how to break the loop when there is space/New Line/particular letter..
Tried with \s--Space,\n--New line or giving letter..but was not successful..

Answer (score 2):

Below code will do.

```
for letter in '''Break the execution of the loop while reading string 
if there is a New line/Space/particular Letter''': 
   print (letter)
   if letter in ['\n',' ']:
     break
```

You can add letters to the list `['\n',' ','a']` like so. FYI. The code loop through each and every letter in the string. I assume, this is what your requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you haven't indented the code of break statement in if statement.
And making a list of all the conditions in which you wanna break should be appended in a code and then check whether that character is in list or not.
 Note:- "/s may not be valid for space , you might wanna use ' ' . "